# How to keep markup separate from content with Gulp?

Tags: javascript, html, npm, preprocessor, gulp

I want to keep my content separate from HTML. I don't want to use any HTML Templating engine like Jade, HAML etc. I want to use raw HTML Only.

I'm using gulp for html pages generation

For example

content1 = `<p>content of content 1</p>`

content2 = `<h4>content of content 2</h4>`

In page1.html

```
<div class="content">
 <p>content of content 1</p>
</div>
```

In page2.html

```
<p class="content">
 <h4>content of content 2</h4>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use gulp-inject plugin
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject

```
var inject = require('gulp-inject')

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <!-- inject:content:html -->
    <!-- contents of html partials will be injected here -->
  <!-- endinject -->
</div>
</body>
</html>

gulp.src('./src/index.html')
  .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['./src/partials/content.html']), {
    starttag: '<!-- inject:content:{{ext}} -->',
    transform: function (filePath, file) {
      // return file contents as string 
      return file.contents.toString('utf8')
    }
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'));
```

Comment: I don't want to reference content of each component in my gulpfile

Comment: you can create a separate gulpfile for those tasks, and call it with your main gulpfile, maybe it's ok for you